# Why is my code to detect a cycle in a graph not printing anything?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, graph

I have written the code to check if a cycle exists or not in a graph using breadth-first traversal.
If I declare the adjacency list as vectoradj[n]; then it's okay.
But the problem arises when I use vector<vector>adj(n)
Can someone tell me what is the error? and how can I use the latter option to run my code?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool checkForCycle(int s, int V, vector<vector<int>>adj, vector<int> &visited)
    {
       
        queue<pair<int, int>> q;
        visited[s] = true;
        q.push({s, -1});
        while (!q.empty())
        {
            int node = q.front().first;
            int par = q.front().second;
            q.pop();
 
            for (auto it : adj[node])
            {
                if (!visited[it])
                {
                    visited[it] = true;
                    q.push({it, node});
                }
                else if (par != it)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
bool isCycle(int V,vector<vector<int>>adj)
    {
        vector<int> vis(V - 1, 0);
        for (int i = 1; i <= V; i++)
        {
            if (!vis[i])
            {
                if (checkForCycle(i, V, adj, vis))
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }

int main() {
    int n, m;
    cout<<"Enter number of vertices :\n";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Enter number of edges :\n";
    cin>>m;
    vector<vector<int>>adj(n);
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        int u, v;
        cin>>u>>v;
        adj[u].push_back(v);
        adj[v].push_back(u);
    }
    
    cout<<endl;
    if(isCycle(n,adj))
        cout<<"cycle present int the graph";
    else
        cout<<"No cycle present";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your compiler should be warning you that not every path in `isCycle` returns a value. Fixing that undefined behavior may or may not solve this issue, but can't hurt.

Comment: Can you describe what exactly is going wrong? Does the program exit without printing anything? Does it throw an exception? Or is it getting stuck in a loop? Have you tried debugging? Also, the loop in `isCycle` goes out of borders on `vis` vector

Comment: it prints nothing

Comment: Are you getting a error ? I got a segmentation fault while running the code

Comment: Change all your vector accesses to `at` instead of using `[]`, it'll show you where you go out of bounds. For example in `isCycle` valid indexes for `vis` are `0` to `V - 2` but you're accessing from `1` to `V`

Comment: @DeepakPatankar No I am not getting any error. Just no output is getting printed

Comment: @AlanBirtles can you make the changes you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

okay so the error resolves if I use

```
vector<vector<int>>adj(n+1);
```

instead of

```
vector<vector<int>>adj(n);
```

Comment: To make this answer helpful, you should explain *why* this is a correct solution.

Comment: The code still has undefined behaviour. You should turn on more compiler warnings.

Comment: What's the reason?